# How to initialize/construct deep nested structs in Julia?

Tags: struct, constructor, initialization, julia

I want to create some deeper nested structs. It seems the [Setfield.jl](https://github.com/jw3126/Setfield.jl) package is sufficient to fill them. But I'm struggling with the initialization of the (empty) structs to fill them later iteratively. These are the structs looks like:

```
struct Bands
   B0::String
   B1::String
   B2::String
   B3::String
   B4::String
   B5::String
   .
   .
   .
   B25::String
end 


struct Masks
   mask1::Bands
   mask2::Bands
   mask3::Bands
   mask4::Bands
   mask5::Bands
   mask6::String
end
```

I've tried inner constructors and as described here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#Incomplete-Initialization-1. It seems that I have to set all values before like described at https://jw3126.github.io/Setfield.jl/stable/intro/. 
How can I initialize the nested struct, in that case 131 values at once?

Comment: At the very least you have to make them mutable, that is `mutable struct Bands`, etc.

Comment: Also, to clarify what you are trying to do, add a minimal example, where you just have one or two fields in each struct definition. Right now I cannot tell what's not working for you.

Comment: To initialize them? As far as I understand Setfields.jl works with immutable structs.

Comment: OK, but this will create a _new_ instance, not update the initial one. Anyway, a minimal example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create default constructors that just put empty objects for all fields which you can update later, for example

```
julia> struct Bands
           B0::String
           B1::String

           # Create a constructor that puts an empty String ("") for each field
           Bands() = new(("" for _ in 1:length(fieldnames(Bands)))...)

           # Define a vararg constructor
           Bands(args...) = new(args...)
       end

julia> struct Masks
           mask1::Bands
           mask2::Bands

           # Create a constructor that puts an empty Bands (Bands()) for each field
           Masks() = new((Bands() for _ in 1:length(fieldnames(Masks)))...)

           # Define a vararg constructor
           Masks(args...) = new(args...)
       end

julia> masks = Masks()
Masks(Bands("", ""), Bands("", ""))

julia> using Setfield

julia> masks = @set masks.mask1 = Bands("hello", "world") # Set a field of masks
Masks(Bands("hello", "world"), Bands("", ""))

julia> masks = @set masks.mask2.B0 = "hello" # Set a field of masks.mask2
Masks(Bands("hello", "world"), Bands("hello", ""))
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the varargs constructor. This is automatically defined, except then you should define `Bands()` as an outer constructor.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much for the quick help! Just to mention, `...` seems not to work in the `new()` function in Julia 1.1.0 (`ERROR: syntax: ... is not supported inside "new"`)

Comment: It is needed if you define the empty inner constructor as I did. An alternative would be to define the empty constructors on the outside, and then it is not needed.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. @Piotr De, don't put the empty constructor on the inside. Make it an outer constructor. Then you don't need the varargs one at all. Simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

For your scenario using `Parameters.jl` will result with a much cleaner code (additionally since `String` is immutable your `Bands` `struct` needs to be mutable.

```
using Parameters

@with_kw mutable struct Bands
    B0::String = ""
    B1::String = ""
end

@with_kw struct Masks
    mask1::Bands = Bands()
    mask2::Bands = Bands()
end
```

In this way your code is clean, readable and you do not need to define a huge load of constructors.